# Mobile Phone Signal Flash Light 3-12V - not working. Circuit viable?

Tags: antenna, cellphone, detector, circuit-design

Another ebay-heist that does not work as adverstised. I build it, and tested with some normal g3 cellphones, but no dice. My antenna at J2 is an 8cm long wire (not really lambda/4 of anything, but i piecemeal snipped it down from 18cm to see whether there was some sort of resonance sweet spot) that i slightly coiled. The DIY inductance L1 was very loosely specified ("5 to 10 turns") so i did 6 turns at 3mm diameter.
It's supposed to take 3-12V, and blink whenever a mobile phone in the vicinity gets a call. 
[image: The circuit in question]

I'd love to know whether the circuit itself is viable, what needs to change, and a short intro to what is supposed to be happening.
(I guess Q3 needs to go active for the LED to blink, so Q2 would have to stop being active as it otherwise pulls the base of Q3 to ground. So i guess the oscillation in C1/L1 somehow wiggles C2 and intermittently quenches Q2 ... or something?)
Thanks!

Comment: I wonder how this is supposed to distinguish between calls and data activitiy

Comment: And why should the led blink? Maybe there is some kind of 'blinking preamble' when receiving a call?

Comment: We need to have an ebay tag that automatically erases questions once posted.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit itself might work.

In DC Q2 is on, its collector is low, Q3 is off and the led is off. Q1 is in AFR but the DC value of its collector does not affect the circuit.

When you receive a call some current is induced in the antenna. Low frequency components are shorted to ground by the coil, while higher frequencies can possibly bias the diode and steal some base current from Q1. That is strange because it seems to me that Q1 gets turned more off, Q2 more on, Q3 more off, no luck with the LED. I think the diode should be reversed, and you can even omit C1.

I also think that some capacitor in parallel with L1 might help, the resonant frequency should equal the carrier frequency you want to detect.